# How can I scope a CMake function so it can't be accessed from outside a file?

Tags: cmake, scope, cmake-modules

I'm trying to write some CMake code in a relatively complex project and I have a module that internally includes another module. The problem is, whenever I include my module, all of the functioned defined in the module it internally includes become available at a global level! This effectively is polluting my global namespace with a bunch of functions I didn't explicitly ask for.

For example:

```
# CMakeLists.txt

# Include my module
include(MyModule)

# Call a function from my module
my_module_function()

# HERE IS THE PROBLEM -- functions from "AnotherModule" are visible here!
# This call works
another_module_function()
```

Inside my module:

```
# MyModule.cmake

# Include another module
#  - This other module is written and supported by someone else so I can't modify it
#  - No functions from "AnotherModule" will be used outside of "MyModule"
include(AnotherModule)

# Define my function
function(my_module_function)

    # Call a function from the other module
    another_module_function()
endfunction()
```

Is there any way inside `MyModule.cmake` that I can import the functions from `AnotherModule.cmake` without having them be visible outside of my own module? This other module is written by someone else so I don't have control over it and it includes other functions with very generic names like one called `parse_arguments` that could potentially cause naming conflicts later on.

Making the functions from `AnotherModule.cmake` fully invisible outside of `MyModule.cmake` would be ideal, but even if there were a simple way to just simulate a namespace for the imported functions to be in that would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In CMake macros and functions has **global visibility** and nothing can change that.

Often a function, "internal" to some module, is defined with underscore (`_`) prefix. Such prefix plays the role of a signal to outer code "not to use me". But this is only a convention, CMake doesn't enforce anything about underscore-prefixed names.

If including a module has only **immediate effects**, that is defines custom commands/targets but does not export functions/macros/variables for outer code, you may consider to wrap it with **external project** (`ExternalProject_Add`). An external project is a separate CMake project, and none its CMake things like variables or functions are visible outside it.

Comment: I don't think `ExternalProject_Add` would work in this case since the modules aren't really projects at all by themselves. They just provide a few functions that I need within a certain scope, then I no longer care about these functions and don't want them bleeding out into the rest of my project. For my own modules I've adopted a naming convention where I prefix functions with a sort of "namespace", but that doesn't work when the module comes from someone else and I can't change the name of every function.

Comment: I may have to submit a bug to the module author for one of the modules I include because most of the functions are sensibly named in a way that they wouldn't collide with my own, but it also defines a macro called `parse_arguments` that definitely could have a name collision with something else.